# Openlayers5 does not work in Internet explorer 11

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

The Openlayers5 simple example does not work in Internet Explorer 11.
It works correctly in Chrome and in Mozilla.

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/simple.html

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [an ongoing issue](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/8356) that should be resolved soon.

There is a PR (Pull Request) in the pipe e.g https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/8364